# Best way to turn a string into 2 variables

Tags: php, string, variables

I'm having some trouble parsing a first name and last name from a string into 2 different variables.

The string is always in this format: "Smith, John" or "Doe, Jane"

Is there a function out that can split the first and last name to 2 different variables to something like...

```
$firstname = "John"
$lastname = "Smith"
```

Comment: Have you tried putting them in an array with use of http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `list` with `explode` like this:

```
list($firstname, $lastname) = explode(',', $yourString);
```

You may need to use `trim` to remove any whitespace from those vars.

Comment: Would you then need to `trim` the `$firstname` to remove the space?

Comment: Well yeah, thats basically what i meant :P

Comment: yeah, probably need the trim, but exactly what I was going to suggest

Comment: Just map the array: `array_map('trim', explode(',', $yourString));`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `list($lastname, $firstname)`?

Comment: @Rocket: True, I did not focus naming convention there. Thought it was same like here in Pakistan eg firstname, lastname order :)

Answer (score 1):

explode() splits a string based upon another string and returns an array.

You could do:

```
$name = "Smith, John";

$name_array = array();

$name_array = explode(",", $name);
```

Comment: You don't need `$name_array = array();`, it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with regexp for this so that there could be slight variations in the input (i.e. "Smith, John", "Smith ,John", "Smith , John" or "Smith,John")

You could do something like this for regexp "\w([a-z]+)\w" and then last name would be your first match and first name would be your second match.

Comment: Or you could use a regex like `/([a-z]+)\s?,\s?([a-z]+)/i`  http://ideone.com/AX57U

Comment: I would look into preg_split with the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE. check the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: What does that do, any why does it help here?

Comment: My bad. I misread the documentation for PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE. I thought you could use it to put the whole format in their and then have the names as capture groups. preg_split returns an array from a string delimited by the supplied pattern. If you put a capture group in the pattern, it will return that along with items delimited in the string.

Comment: `preg_split` is the same as `explode` except it uses a regex.  Here, I guess you could do `preg_split('/\s?,\s?/', $str);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = "Smith, John";
$expl = explode(', ', $name);
$firstname = $expl[1];
$lastname = $expl[0];
echo $firstname.' '.$lastname;
```